# How to exclude the column if all the values in column are null in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

Let's say I have a table `Employee` which has columns `FirstName, LastName, Address` and `Position`.

Now when `select * from Employee` runs, the result is displayed as follows:

[image]

We can see that the value of `Address` is `NULL` for all the rows.

If such a condition occurs, I need only three columns `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Position` to be displayed.

Similarly, if the `Position` column is null for all the values then I want to exclude the `Position` column and display only `FirstName` and `LastName`.

How can I do that?

Comment: You could only do this with dynamic SQL, as when you `SELECT` the dataset must be well defined. Also, checking *every single column* in *every single row* is not a cheap operation. Personally, I would simply suggest you don't go down this path. Perhaps what you should really be doing is reconsidering if you really need said column in your table if every value is `NULL`.

Comment: Don't try to solve it at the database level - see if it can be solved at the *presentation* layer, e.g. within the application or report building tool that's requesting this result set. In SQL, any given query has a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and types.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Address IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName,Lastame,Position FROM EMPLOYEE
END
```